# Couldn't connect to display error when using tcl lib in python

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

I'm trying to call a hello world tcl script in python on linux server, but it generates `_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display` error.

Error as follows:

```
r = Tkinter.Tk()
File "/apps/cad/default/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1764, in __init__
  self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)"
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display
```

I've searched on this problem, but most of the solution is to use `Agg` in `matplotlib.use()`, but I tried it and it doesn't work.

test.py

```
import Tkinter

r = Tkinter.Tk()

r.tk.eval("source test.tcl")
```

test.tcl

```
puts "hello py"
```

What causes this problem, and how am I going to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Are you running this on a machine that has a display? If you're running it on a server, you probably don't have a display. Tkinter requires a display.

Comment: BTW, I've got a specific solution for matplotlib that works better than the usual advice found online; matplotlib is particularly tricky and awkward to workaround as there are parts that are utterly underdocumented, but there _is_ a way to force things without going as far as installing an X server. My answer below is for the more general problem where that can't be avoided in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Tk, and hence Tkinter, *requires* an X server (often called a “display”) on Linux so that it has something on which to pop up windows. Because that's its primary purpose; to draw windows. (How to connect to the X server is described in the `DISPLAY` environment variable.)

Servers don't usually have displays. If you need one, use the Xvfb program (which creates a Virtual Frame Buffer, a synthetic display) and that works fine as long as you don't actually need to interact with the windows that your script creates. If you *do* need to interact with the windows, you'll have to find a way to make them display somewhere else. This might be by using X forwarding with ssh, or a VNC connection somehow, or… well, there's lots of options. *You are advised to not write your code to require user interaction if it is going to run on a server.* It can be done, but it's devilishly tricky and should be avoided where unnecessary.

You'll need to read up on Xvfb to see how to launch it and your Python code in such a way that they can find each other.